# Proving Equivalence of TM and DFA

Tags: computation-theory, dfa, turing-machines, formal-languages, halting-problem

I'm trying to prove that TM = DFA is undecidable using reduction from Halting Problem
Theoretically I understand that Turing Machine captures all the computable functions and DFA only capture the functions that can be computed in constant space therefore TM = DFA is undecidable.

Here are my steps:
Suppose that R that decide L(M)=L(D)

**EQ_DM = { [D,M] | L(M) = L(D) }** 
and we create a turing machine

**HALT_TM = { [M,w]  |  (M halt on input w→Accept 

                M did not halt on input w→Reject)}**

How do I construct a D & M so R[D,M] tells if M halt on w?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that it is decidable whether a TM and a DFA accept the same language. You can use this to solve the halting problem for a general TM.

Given any TM M and word w, construct M' so that whenever M enters the halt-reject state, M' enters the halt-accept state. Now, M' is a TM that accepts every string that causes M to halt. Now construct M'' from M' so that L(M'') is the intersection of L(M') and {w}, where w is any word. You can always construct M'' using the Cartesian product machine construction given a DFA for {w} and M'.

Since it is decidable whether L(M'') is equal to that of a DFA - say, the DFA for {w} - we can say whether M'' accepts {w}. If it accepts w, then L(M') contains w and if L(M') contains w, M halts on w. If M'' does not accept w, L(M') does not contain w and, therefore, M does not halt on w.